# Customize bpy.context.space_data.overlay.show_stats

Tags: mesh, customization, measurement

Can I customize the data shown in *bpy.context.space_data.overlay.show_stats* ?

My goal is:
if there are 2 selected vertices, then show the distance between them.

Same for 2 selected and parallel edges (or faces).

Comment: Can you run `bpy.context.space_data.overlay.show_stats`? In my case, `bpy.context.space_data` has no `overlay`.